# Using GAE datastore in different versions

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, versioning

I'm using GAE as my app back-end. For production environment I use the a the 2nd version. while  continue developing on the 1st version.

The problem is that both versions use the same datastore. Is there a way to define versions to the datastore. So, entities used in the development won't even be queried in production?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: You must define another application. All versions of an application use the same data store.

Comment: Agree with original comment, you could use names spaces, but then that introduces the whole notion of namespaces , which is probably not a good idea.  A seperate test instance is a much better idea.

Comment: Why are you developing in the production environment in the first place? That's what the local dev server is for.

Answer (score 0):

All versions of an application share the same datastore.  This is actually very useful because it lets you upload a Go component and a Python component as separate versions that access the same datastore.

For the purposes of testing, if you want a separate database, use a separate app id.

Answer (score -1):

Use namespaces
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/multitenancy
It separates everything including memcached etc.

Comment: It also overcomplicates things, and may also cause issues if he later decides to use namespaces for something more useful than just testing.

Comment: I dont see how it complicates things, its just a simple namespace and you can keep using them if you later want to use them also for something else (do something simple like a prefix so it doesnt collide with your debug nsmespace). Its also the only real option besides deploying a separate instance, and doing that doesnt give you the exact configuration as the 'real' deployment. Using the local (simulated) instance is usually not an option as it behaves very differently on some apengine features.

Comment: You'll need to explicitly add code that detects some operation as being a test operation, and using the test namespace.  So you don't end up testing the exact same configuration.  Plus you can't test stuff like blobstore operations that don't support namespaces.  It's much, much simpler to change the app name in app.yaml, redeploy, and know that you have an exact duplicate running for test and production.